How to remove the Input box in native mobile keyboard (iOS & Android)?

Good day, in Unity, is there any way or plugin that can remove the input box in the mobile keyboard?
because its kinda redundant seeing the input in our input box and the mobile keyboard.
The goal is to implement this in IOS and Android devices.
Thank you.

Thanks everyone, I found out that I just need to "check" or toggle the "Hide Mobile Input" in TMP_Input inspector.


The documentation at below says you can disable it with
TouchScreenKeyboard.hideInput = true;

I haven't tried it so if it works please let me know.
Unity Keyboard Documentation

Hello @Altay Turan I appreciate the feedback, I tried but it doesn't work.

https://discussions.unity.com/t/remove-keyboard-input-field/691641/8
Check this out.
